# GPG Encrypting Mercurial Patchbomb e-mails

Tags: security, email, mercurial, gnupg

Is it possible to use patchbomb to not just sign a diff with your key but to encrypt the diff to be sent to a specific key as well? For example, I want to send a diff to a coworker of mine via e-mail, but I want to encrypt the diff so that only he can read it (theoretically ;)). Does patchbomb support this?

Comment: How do you sign your diff ? AFAIK, patchbomb can't sign the diffs itself, so I think you're already using something else for this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> [...] I want to send a diff to a coworker of mine via e-mail, but I want to encrypt the diff so that only he can read it (theoretically ;)). Does patchbomb support this?

The answer is **no**. The [patchbomb extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PatchbombExtension) does not work with the [gpg extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GpgExtension) in any way. It doesn't know how to sign emails and it doesn't know how to encrypt them either.

Even the [commitsigs extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommitsigsExtension) cannot be used for this since the meta data it puts into the changesets isn't exported by `hg email`.

Your best option is to use `hg export` to get a patch and then copy-paste the patch into a mail client that does support encryption/signing.